# commenting out code blocks in javascript

Tags: javascript, block, comments

I did a google search for the answer but I've probably overlooked something obvious... I wish to comment out a block of code that has the potential to have nested comments, where they can terminate the parent comment early.  In c I've seen it done like follows:

```
#if 0
    /* Code */
#endif
```

but js doesn't seem to have standard preprocessor.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that I can comment out any block by doing:

1||
/* code block */

It even works before statements because js seems to treat them as expressions as well, for instance

1||
if(1)
  /* code */

will 'comment out' that if block.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just do something like:

```
if ( ! "DEBUG" ) {

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

javascript don't provide preprocessor but you can use use third-party library

http://code.google.com/p/jsmake-preprocessor/

ex)

```
/*@ifdef DEBUG_MODE */

console.log("development server is in debug mode!");

/*@end */
```

Comment: So no standard way of commenting out code blocks?  Oh well.  I think I'll just work around the limitation rather than extend the code.  It's not like I need a preprocessor for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript multiline comments, also known as block comments, start with a forward slash followed by an asterisk (/*) and end with an asterisk followed by a forward slash (*/). They do not require a comment delimiter character on every line and may contain newlines

[source](https://www.udacity.com/blog/2021/05/javascript-comments.html)